# keras can't visualize none embedding layer use tensorboar projector

Tags: keras, tensorboard, embedding, visualize

i try to visualize a classification program using Keras.callbacks.tensorboard. the method has arguments like embeddings_freq\embeddings_layer_names\embeddings_data. i assign the last FC layer to  embedding_layer_names. And it doesn't work.
throwed errors:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Not found: Resource localhost/FC_embedding/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.
         [[node strided_slice/_assign (defined at /home/admin1/anaconda3/envs/max/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
         [[ReadVariableOp_1/_191]]
  (1) Not found: Resource localhost/FC_embedding/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.
         [[node strided_slice/_assign (defined at /home/admin1/anaconda3/envs/max/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
```